# What type of snail is this?

Tags: aquarium, snails

I bought some fish from a pet store and a few weeks later I noticed that there were a few snails in my tank and now it has been 2 months since I bought them home and there are a lot more then what I had before. My question is, what type of snails are they?
Below is a picture of one of my snails.

[image]

Comment: This might be a better fit for SE biology. They have species identification tag.

Comment: if you want to remove the ramshorn snails or other types of freshwater snails this is the solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anentome_helena they move fast and multiply slowly so they will never be a problem in your tank,when they run out of prey they will eat regular fish food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramshorn; usually darker shades of brown and red.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have had ramshorn snails before and the ones I have now don't look like them.